# Windows Docker image with .NET and Ghostscript

Tags: .net, docker, dockerfile

I have a Dockerfile like this:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore:ltsc2019

# Download Ghostscript installer
ADD https://github.com/ArtifexSoftware/ghostpdl-downloads/releases/download/gs9540/gs9540w64.exe C:/ghostscript/gs9540w64.exe

# Install Ghostscript
RUN C:/ghostscript/gs9540w64.exe /S

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0 AS build
ARG BUILD_CONFIGURATION=Release
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["DotnetCoreApiWithDocker.csproj", "."]
RUN dotnet restore "./././DotnetCoreApiWithDocker.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/."
RUN dotnet build "./DotnetCoreApiWithDocker.csproj" -c $BUILD_CONFIGURATION -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
ARG BUILD_CONFIGURATION=Release
RUN dotnet publish "./DotnetCoreApiWithDocker.csproj" -c $BUILD_CONFIGURATION -o /app/publish /p:UseAppHost=false

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
CMD [" dotnet", "DotnetCoreApiWithDocker.dll"]
```

I successfully build an image, but when I try to run interactive session it returns me this:

docker exec -it 9968e57a6180 powershell.exe

```
container 9968e57a6180b1be147f2e8bb10dc123c612e3b34c85d702936f34591ce3ef2e encountered an error during hcs::System::CreateProcess: failure in a Windows system call: The system cannot find the file specified. (0x2)  
[Event Detail:  Provider: 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000]  
[Event Detail:  Provider: 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000]
                                                                                                                                      [Event Detail: onecore\vm\compute\management\orchestration\vmhostedcontainer\processmanagement.cpp(173)\vmcomputeagent.exe!00007FF6C0869FDB: (caller: 00007FF6C081E19A) Exception(3) tid(7bc) 80070002 The system cannot find the file specified.
    CallContext:[\Bridge_ProcessMessage\VmHostedContainer_ExecuteProcess]
                                                                           Provider: 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000]
```

For me it seems that there is something wrong with CMD/ENTRYPOINT command. I see container running with docker ps command but Im not able to enter interactive session for some reason.
Any help or tip is greatly appreciated.

I tried changing Dockerfile and making multiple adjustment that I found online, but no luck...